# transforming $\chi^2(n)$ distribution to $t$ distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

if we have two independent random variables for both of them $\chi^2(n)$ distribution

Prove it has a t distribution with degree freedom ($n$)
$$\frac{\sqrt n (x_1 +x_2 )}{ \sqrt {x_1 x_2}}$$

Comment: Did you intend $x_1+x_2$ to be in the numerator?

Comment: Do you mean $x_1$ and $x_2$ have chi-square distributions? If so, then $x_1+x_2>0$ with probability $1$, and that doesn't happen with a t-distribution.

Comment: x_1 and x_2 have chi square distribution, i wanna to prove that above relation has t distribution

Comment: Empirically this is heavily right skewed (since one of $x_1$ or $x_2$ can be close to zero when the other is not)

Comment: can i prove this relation or not?

Comment: I have edited your Question. In answer to @MichaelHardy's Comment, you had the TeX `\frac` code in the wrong place to print a fraction. Still I wonder if this is what you intended because it is not true.

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelHardy and @Henry are trying to explain that you *cannot*
prove this because it is not true.

Here is something that *is* true. It is valuely related to what
you posted and might even be what you intended. It illustrates the *definition* of
a random variable with Student's t distribution:

Let $X_1 \sim Norm(0,1)$ and, independently, $X_2 \sim Chisq(df=n).$
Then $$T = \frac{\sqrt{n}X_1}{\sqrt{X_2}} = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt{X_2/n}} \sim T(n),$$
Student's t distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. You can find the
proof in many mathematical statistics texts.

The simulation below in R statistical software demonstrates this relationship
for $df = 15.$

```
m = 10^6;  df = 15;  x1 = rnorm(m);  x2 = rchisq(m, df)
t = sqrt(df)*x1/sqrt(x2)
mean(t);  var(t);  df/(df-2)
## -0.0001963736    # aprx E(T) = 0
## 1.15594          # aprs Var(T) = 15/13
## 1.153846         # exact Var(T)
quantile(t)         # min, aprx quartiles, max
##            0%           25%           50%           75%          100% 
## -1.012026e+01 -6.929461e-01 -5.062215e-04  6.930493e-01  7.579955e+00 
qt(c(.25,.75), df)
## -0.6911969  0.6911969  # exact lower and upper quartiles of T(15)
```

Below is a histogram of the million realizations of $T$ simulated in
this way. Student's t distributions tend to have heavy tails, hence the
'long' horizontal axis to accommodate a few stragling values far from 0
in both directions (which produce bars too short to show at the resolution
of the graph). The curve is the PDF of $T(15).$

[image]

Comment: +1, though I tend to use fewer degrees of freedom for examples like this

Comment: @Henry: Thanks. With small df, the tails are so long that the shape of the distribution in the center is not clear. In particular, df  = 1 or 2 work very badly. Even with df=15 there are extreme values out to about -10 and +7.